# General Workflow for bots

Tags: api, chat, real-time, bots, yammer

I've been tasked with setting up a bot to work with Yammer, as we are investigating using Yammer as an office communication tool.

Bots are essential to workflow, so they can notify users of important real-time events and can respond immediately to queries about system states even when not in the office without the need of complicated remote-desktop systems.

I've looked into Hubot, which has a Yammer adapter using a deprecated real-time API. However, this only reacts to posts made to public groups, and does not respond to private messages.

How would I start implementing something (which APIs to look at) to receive and send private messages in real-time? I feel this surely must be possible for a communication platform like Yammer (otherwise this defeats the point?), but I cannot find anything in the API documentation.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few changes in the hubot-yammer and yammer modules would make the adapters work with private groups as well.

Here is what I have done to make it work with private groups.

## main.js:

I have modified the main.js of yammer module to pass the group id up front and modified it to call the messagesInGroup API of yammer to listen to private group messages.

```
RealTime.prototype.messages = function (g_id,cb) {
  this.yam.messagesInGroup(g_id,function (e, body) {
```

## Yammer.coffee:

Further modified Yammer.coffee script to call the yammer module with private group id.

```
class YammerRealtime extends EventEmitter under options

 if options.access_token? 
  @g_id = options.g_id

  ## Yammer API call methods
  listen: (callback) ->
    @yammer.realtime.messages @g_id,(err, data) ->
```

With above changes hubot-yammer listens to private groups and responds back.